# Use CSS-classes defined inside an iframe, outside of the iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

we have a content management system that deletes the `<style>` tag. As a workaround I would like to implement an iframe that has a `<style>`-tag with my classes in it, and use these classes outside the iframe as well. 
Do you know a way to do this? Is it possible?

Comment: example please. make jsfiddle or something

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible. But if you can use an iframe, why not dynamically load the CSS through, say, ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you want to reuse `css styles` that are defined inside `iframe` (another web page)? You can append all the `styles` from an `iframe` with `javascript`. Here is an example of that.

[jsfiddle: styles you want to reuse](https://jsfiddle.net/2tpLruj4/4/)

There is only one `css rule` inside (for demonstration purposes only), but there can be as many as you want. Now let reuse that class (`.someclass`).

[jsfiddle: reused styles](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxa88u9w/12/)

You can acces iframe document through `contentWindow`.

```
var exampleIFrame = document.getElementById('exampleiframe');
var exampleIFrameStyles = exampleIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('style');
```

Then append all the `iframe` styles to the current document's `head`. I've merged all the `styles` into one.

```
var tmpStyle = document.createElement('style');
tmpStyle.id = "iframe-style";
for (var i = 0; i < exampleIFrameStyles.length; ++i) {
  tmpStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(exampleIFrameStyles[i].innerHTML));
}
document.head.appendChild(tmpStyle);
```

Please see fiddle(s). I hope that helps!